# How to reconcile CAPM with Discounted Cash Flows valuation?

Tags: capm, valuation, dcf, allocation

According to CAPM (in its most basic form) our asset allocation will only depend on the expected returns and the covariance matrix of returns. If we also consider the risk-free asset and assume that everyone follows the CAPM, then the optimal weights allocated in the stock market will be those of the market portfolio, and the firm with the highest weight will be the one with highest value.

Therefore, market value of a firm seems to be independent from its future cashflows.

Is this a problem of CAPM? Maybe this information is integrated through expected returns?

Thank you very much.

Comment: It’s not a problem of CAPM. “Firm with the highest weight will have the highest value” is circular. How is the value of that firm determined? It is determined by using CAPM expected return to discount future cash flows. Then expected return is baked into your value.